# Clicking on link inside dropdown menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `dropdown` menu which works fine, but when I am adding a link inside the `dropdown` menu then the link doesn't work.

Check the fiddle here and try to click on the link2 and the `google` link; 
It's the `google` link that doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="link">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            Content for dropdown 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.link a').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.link').siblings().children('.dropdown').fadeOut();
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown').fadeToggle();
});

 $(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
var container = $(".dropdown");

if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    container.hide();
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
    .link {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

.link a {
    padding: 10px;
}

.link .dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    color: white;
    background: #999;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abLku7e1/2

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: That is because you are calling event.preventDefault(). This prevent the default behaviour of the `a` elements click, which would be to open the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` is the problem, it's on `.link a` which is **ALL** `a` decendents of `.link`. Use `.link > a` for the parent level links.

`>` means direct child.

Comment: Also, note that links don't open in jsfiddle. Once you change it to `.link > a`, use middle mouse button or right-click+open in new tab to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.link > a').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.link').siblings().children('.dropdown').fadeOut();
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown').fadeToggle();
});
```

You only want to target direct descendants of .link.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.  My CSS menu had something like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#internal link"> Working </a></li>
  <li><a href="http://external link"> Not working </a></li>
</ul>
```

Like you, my javascript used `e.preventDefault();` to close the menu once clicked and for the external link it would close the menu without actually going to that external link.

I solved it by adding a span:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#internal link"> Working </a></li>
  <li> <span> <a href="http://external link"> </span> Now its working </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the JS code to only act on the first link not all sub links like below

```
    $('.link>a').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.link').siblings().children('.dropdown').fadeOut();
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown').fadeToggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".dropdown");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

note link>a mean only first level

http://jsfiddle.net/neka5u0d/

Comment: Awesome when someone exactly copies your answer a full three minutes after.

Comment: when I posted the answer I haven't seen yours first, it is common to have two individuals reaching the same result, I don't see that offensive; still the way you reacted was a little bit childish?!